# How to control the number of async http client requests initiated from a stream in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to read a large stream of binary data, chunk it into smaller parts and perform a PUT.

```
data.pipe(new BlockStream(1024*1024)).pipe(through(success, end))

function success(data) {
    var params = {/*host, port, etc...*/
    var req = http.request(params, (e, r) => {/*handle response*/})
    req.push(data)
    req.end()
}

function end() {cb()}
```

Ideally, I would like to have the request complete before moving onto the next and simultaneously not block other JS code from executing. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using [through](https://github.com/dominictarr/through).  You can use the `pause` and `resume` methods to control the data flow:

```
var inProgress = 0;
var MAX_IN_PROGRESS = 5; //or whatever number

data.pipe(new BlockStream(1024*1024)).pipe(through(success, end))

function success(data) {
    var params = {/*host, port, etc...*/
    inProgress++;
    if(inProgress == MAX_IN_PROGRESS) {
        this.pause();
    }
    var that = this;
    var req = http.request(params, (e, r) => {/*handle response*/})
    req.push(data)
    req.end(function() {
        inProgress--;
        if(that.paused) {
            that.resume();
        }
    });
}

function end() {cb()}
```

What we're doing here is keeping a count of how many requests are currently in progress.  When we start one, we pause if that brings us up to the max number, and when we finish one we resume if we are currently paused.

Comment: Ultimately, Tim's answer helped me out more (book mentioned is a great resource), but this one will likely help others who read this question since it has an example so setting this as the posted answer. Thanks!